# Appraisal came in low, but appraiser was given incorrect price

Tags: united-states, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer, appraisal

I just received an appraisal report claiming that the house I'm buying is worth $7,000 under the price that I'm paying. However, the appraisal report shows that the appraiser was given a contract price of $12,000 less than it actually is.

Various websites claim that relatively few houses are appraised under contract price, and the report explicitly says that the appraiser considered the contract while appraising the property.

What can/should I do here? I can find an extra $7,000 to match that price, but I'd really rather not if possible (I'm doing a 20% down payment already). Are there actually benefits to a lower appraisal (perhaps tax related?) that mean that this is good for me and I should keep my mouth shut about it? Can I force the bank to re-appraise it? Is that worth it (as the sellers would presumably notice a second appraiser coming by)?

Comment: Can you for the bank to re-appraise?  Probably not.  Can you ask them and offer to pay for an updated appraisal?  It's possible.  In theory the appraisal should not depend on the offer price but in practice it often does.

Comment: Well, yes, the "in practice" bit is the bit I'm concerned about. If all that this will affect is the extra $7k I may just send the originator an annoyed email and check any more documents I get from them *very* carefully for accuracy...

Comment: A realtor I'm working with in the midwest told me that almost every house he's been involved with has had the appraisal come in under the contract price. Buyers are just having to find the extra cash.

Comment: Surely the point of an appraisal is that the surveyor tells the bank what the house is actually worth, not how much you want it to be worth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now is the time to sit down with your real estate agent to chart out several courses of action. You don't want to lose the earnest money deposit. You would like to save the deal, without having to write a bigger check.

The seller wants to save the deal. Of course they want to get the full amount that was negotiated.

In many places people are bidding over the list price. Sellers and their agents are being aggressive when setting the asking price. It is possible that the winning offer can go to far above the rest of the recent sales, which makes the lender nervous.

The question for the seller is do they think putting it back on the market will get more money?

It is possible that a different lender will be more willing to support te negoiated price.

> Are there actually benefits to a lower appraisal (perhaps tax
> related?) that mean that this is good for me and I should keep my
> mouth shut about it?

If the market keeps rising, you may find that the tax assessment on the next reappraisal may be above what you bid.  So there might not be much in the way of tax savings.